# How do you access HTTP GET parameters in Nginx prior to version 0.7.8?

Tags: configuration, nginx

The [changelog](http://nginx.net/CHANGES) lists version 0.7.8 as the version that introduces the `$arg_X` notation to access the HTTP GET parameter `X` from within `nginx.conf`.

Unfortunately, the wiki is very up to date.  How do you access HTTP GET parameters from within `nginx.conf` before this version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, the best I have is matching against `$args`.

For instance, instead of saying `if ($arg_user = "jim")` you can say `if ($args = "user=jim")`.  This particular example only works for a single argument, since multiple arguments can come in any order; that case should be handled with regular expressions.